# Are there alternatives to extending/overriding private classes/methods?

Tags: java, android

I want to customize the way a CalendarView is drawn in Android. Here's how CalendarView.java looks in the AOSP source code:

```
public class CalendarView extends FrameLayout{
  private class WeekView extends View{
    protected void onDraw(..){
        drawBackground(..);
        drawWeekNumbersAndDates(..);
        drawWeekSeparators(..);
        drawSelectedDateVerticalBars(..);
    }
    private void drawBackground(..){..}
    private void drawWeekNumbersAndDates(..){..}
    private void drawWeekSeparators(..){..}
    private void drawSelectedDateVerticalBars(..){..}
  }
}
```

Since the relevant bits are declared private, I can't just extend/override them (or can I?). Copying the whole source file and then making changes may be problematic, because the file is part of a package (android.widget) I do not own.

Comment: As my knowledge, there is no way to override. Android has many private fields/inner classes/methods that are not override-able OR inaccessible in extended classes. In my opinion, Google developers didn't design Android API well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Standard overriding is definitely out of the question. Private members aren't even *inherited* so there is no sense in the very concept of "overriding" them in the subclass.

In your case the writers decided to have this class private. It may be inconvenient for your particular purpose, but since everything within a public library which is publicly accessible automatically becomes a part of its API, binding its authors to maintain it for backward compatibility, it is no light decision to make any particular piece of code public. Here the writers decided not to take that step.

So, indeed, reusing by copy-paste (if feasible) could in this case be an appropriate means of achieving your goal. While doing so take care to respect the terms of the library's license.

Comment: But copy-paste doesn't give access to package methods. Unless you want to copy the whole package...

Comment: Yes, depending on the particulars of the code it may be very inconvenient to copy-paste. Sometimes it goes well, sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: @Ypnypn: You can add a package with the same name as the class package and copy the class over to it if you need access to package-private methods. Note that this still won't give you access to the hidden methods that aren't included in the android.jar stub.